# How can I determine the end behavior of a polynomial based on Taylor series?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

[image]

I know this represents the cos(x) function, but what does it mean that the summation starts with 1 and ends with 21?

This question is for my review sheet for an exam I have. Also, if I were to write the last three terms, does that mean they would be $x^6/6!, x^8/8!$, and $x^{10}/10!$ ?

Comment: Is it implied that we are looking at $x \to \infty$? In that case, you can just look at the last (=highest) term of the polynomial.

Comment: The last term is $-x^{42}/42!$, not $x^{10}/10!$

Answer (score 0):

If you truncate a Taylor series to a polynomial, you get something that's a good approximation of the function ... if you're close enough. For larger $x$, the fact that it's just a polynomial takes over, and it separates from the function completely to do its own thing. Since it's a polynomial, that thing is to go to $\pm\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ or $x\to -\infty$. Which sign? That depends on the sign of the coefficient of the largest-degree term and whether that degree is even or odd.

Comment: so if it is even then sign is positive and if it is odd then sign is negative?

Comment: Since you haven't specified what "it" is, out of several possible parameters, I can't answer your question. Or, for that matter, what "sign" refers to.

Comment: how does the summation from 1 to 21 affect the way the polynomial behaves? how it rises and falls? and how would i write the last three terms of this polynomial?